# Try/Catch block does not actually execute the get-eventlog cmdlet

Tags: powershell, try-catch, get-eventlog

For some reason, when I try to use the security option, it does not actually execute the get-eventlog cmdlet, but writes it to the screen as though it were quoted. The other logs work without the try catch block, but whenever I set them up with the try catch block, they still function as though the cmdlet were quoted.

```
$eventlogname = Read-Host "Which event log category do wish to view? Enter Application, Security, Setup, System, or Forwarded events"
$lognumber = Read-Host "Enter the number of logs you wish to retrieve"

switch 
    ($eventlogname)
{
     Security {
            $logseverity = Read-Host "What event severity do you wish to view? Enter Critical, Warning, Error, FailureAudit, SuccessAudit, or Information"
            $computernameeventlog = Read-Host "Please enter the hostname to query"

            if ($computernameeventlog -eq "localhost" )
            {
            try
                {
                    {
                    Get-EventLog -logname $eventlogname -EntryType $logseverity -Newest $lognumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    }


                            }
                            catch [System.IO.IOException]
                            {
                                Write-Host "The hostname was incorrect or not available."
                            }
                            catch [System.InvalidOperationException]
                            {
                                Write-Host "The event log does not exist"
                            }
                    }
             else
                {

             try{
                    {
                        Get-EventLog -logname $eventlogname -EntryType $logseverity -ComputerName $computernameeventlog -Newest $lognumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
                    }
                        }
                            catch [System.IO.IOException]
                            {
                                Write-Host "The hostname was incorrect or not available."
                            }
                            catch [System.InvalidOperationException]
                            {
                                Write-Host "The event log does not exist"
                            }
                    }
                }

     "Forwarded events"
     {
        $computernamewinevent = Read-Host "Please enter the hostname to query"
        $logseverity = Read-Host "What event severity do you wish to view? Enter Critical, Warning, Error or Information"
        if ($computernamewinevent -eq "localhost")
        {
            Get-WinEvent -logname forwardedevents -MaxEvents $lognumber | where {$_.leveldisplayname -contains $logseverity}
        }
        else
        {
            Get-WinEvent -logname forwardedevents -MaxEvents $lognumber -ComputerName $computername | where {$_.leveldisplayname -contains $logseverity}
        }
    }
    default
    {
    $logseverity = Read-Host "What event severity do you wish to view? Enter Critical, Warning, Error or Information"
    $computernameeventlog = Read-Host "Please enter the hostname to query"

    if ($computernameeventlog -eq "localhost" )

        {
            Get-EventLog -logname $eventlogname -EntryType $logseverity -Newest $lognumber 
        }



    else
        {
            Get-EventLog -logname $eventlogname -EntryType $logseverity -ComputerName $computernameeventlog -Newest $lognumber
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have surrounded the command with brackets (`{` `}`) such as this:

```
{
Get-EventLog -logname $eventlogname -EntryType $logseverity -ComputerName $computernameeventlog -Newest $lognumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
}
```

This will produce a script block, which will not execute but output as a string. What you want is remove the brackets.

Comment: That solved it, but when I added another catch block, it came back.

Comment: can you show me the code for that new issue? OR better make a new question ?

Comment: I ended up completely cleaning it up, and redoing each block.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to fix the various bracket issues that Micky mentioned, your Catch block would still never run.  In the Try block, you must force a terminating error.  You forced it to completely ignore errors:

```
#Note the changed error action:
Get-EventLog -logname $eventlogname -EntryType $logseverity -Newest $lognumber -ErrorAction Stop

#Get some help on the topic:
Get-Help about_Try_Catch_Finally
```

Further reading that might help:

- [about_Try_Catch_Finally](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx)
- [PowerShell.org eBooks](http://powershell.org/wp/ebooks/) - Big Book of PowerShell Error Handling
- [An Introduction to Error Handling in PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx)

---

Lastly, on an aside, consider more readable formatting.  Some popular choices:

```
Try
{
    #Do something
}
Catch 
{
    #Catch
}

Try {
    #Do something
}
Catch {
    #Catch
}
```

Many have strong feelings for and against these and other conventions, but as long as you are consistent, you should be good.  I see a bit of the first example, but then some cases where you indent the first curly bracket instead of lining it up with the keyword.

Cheers!